# Change "Add to Cart" to "Choose Option" for variant product in collection page Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have managed to add an Add to Cart button to my collection page in the Flex theme from Out of the Sandbox. However, for variant products, when you click on the Add to Cart, it automatically adds the default variant product to the Cart. I would like to change this so that instead of "Add to Cart" it displays "Choose Option" on the button and when clicked it takes you to the product page, where you then have to select the variant before adding this to the cart.

My code for the Add to Cart button is:

```
<form method="post" action="/cart/add">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />
<input type="submit" value="{% if product.variants.first.available%}Add to Basket{% else %}Out of Stock{% endif%}" class="button ajax-submit action_button button--add-to-cart" {% unless product.variants.first.available %}disabled{% endunless %} />
</form>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: Try following this [tutorial](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/customize-theme-how-to-add-a-pick-an-option-to-drop-downs) it doesn't show the flex theme but you should find a theme on there with similar files, just have a look through the then follow the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
{% if product.available == false %}
    <span>Out of Stock</span>
{% elsif product.has_only_default_variant %}
    <form method="post" action="/cart/add">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Basket" class="button ajax-submit action_button button--add-to-cart" />
    </form>
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ product.url }}">Choose option</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That's great - thanks. It works now. I have changed the code so that the Choose Option and Out of Stock are displayed in the same button as the Add to Cart.

Comment: Another problem I have now though is that, in the Product page when you click on Add to basket, it shows a ✓ symbol in the Button to show the product was added, and also the Mini-Cart drops down showing what is in the Cart. However with the code above, this only adds the product to the cart, but does not do the other actions. Any idea how to make it do these as well?

Comment: I would need to have a closer look at the code, but I think you would need to trigger the minicart opening with JS. That would mean you would need to add to cart with the Cart API as well: https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart